# Match floats but not dates separated by dot

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to build a regex which can find floats (using a dot or comma as decimal separator) in a string. I ended up with the following:

```
/([0-9]+[.,]{1}[0-9]+)/g
```

Which seems to work fine expect that it matches dates separated by `.` as well:

```
02.01.2000 // Matches 12.34
```

I've tried `([0-9]+[.,]{1}[0-9]+)(?![.,])` but that does not work as I expected it :)

How would I omit the date case, but still pass the following scenarios:

```
I tried some stuff 12.23
D12.34
12.34USD
2.3%
12,2
\n12.1
```

Comment: What about forcing the pattern to match the entire string using `^ $`, and removing the `g` flag?

Comment: @amy I'm searching through a long text with multiple lines

Comment: Are you trying to extract?

Comment: Use this regex [`(?:\d+\.){2}\d+|(\d+[.,]\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/NSWNb5/1) and get your matches in captured group #1

Comment: Try [`(?<!\S)(\d+[.,]\d+)(?!\S)`](https://regex101.com/r/BcTUj2/1)

Comment: @Matt.G: This is Javascript and lookbehind support is limited to newest browsers only.

Comment: @revo yes, I'm extracting.

Comment: @anubhava your regex still matches on `1.2.33`

Comment: @Roland it matches but has no group1 for that match, so it would be discarded

Comment: @danielmoses not true, using `str.match(/(?:\d+\.){2}\d+|(\d+[.,]\d+)/g)` will match that

Comment: @Roland: Yes it will match `1.2.33` but it won't capture it. It will only capture desired numbers in capture group #1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex using alternation:

```
(?:\d+\.){2}\d+|(\d+[.,]\d+)
```

and **extract your matches from captured group #1**.

This regex basically matches and discards date strings on LHS of alternation and then matches and **captures** floating numbers on RHS of alternation.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NSWNb5/1/)

**Code:**

```js
const regex = /(?:\d+\.){2}\d+|(\d+[.,]\d+)/gm;
const str = `I tried some stuff 12.23
D12.34
12.34USD 02.01.2000
2.3%
12,2 02.01.2000
\\n12.1`;
let m;
let results = [];

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (m[1])
    results.push( m[1] );
}

console.log(results);
```

Comment: Thanks, this does the trick. I was using `.match()` which of course gives me different results.

Answer (score 1):

You want to make sure that it isn't surrounded with more ",." or numbers.  Is that right?

`/[^,.0-9]([0-9]+[.,]{1}[0-9]+)[^,.0-9]/g`

Given the following:

```
hi 1.3$ is another 1.2.3
This is a date 02.01.2000
But this 5.30USD is a number.
But a number at the end of a sentance 1.7.
Or a number comma number in a list  4,3,4,5.
```

It will match "1.3" and "5.30"

Using @anubhava's example `(?:\d+\.){2}\d+|(\d+[.,]\d+)` You get the following result:
It will match "1.3", "5.30", "1.7", "4,3", and "4,5"

Moral of the story is you need to think through all the possible scenarios and understand how you want to treat each scenario.  The last line should be a list of 4 numbers.  But is "4,3" by itself two separate numbers or from a country where they use commas to denote decimal?